# How to connect navigation bar which content is taken from JSON to jquery and use button as toggle

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, bootstrap-4

I want to connect navbar which is taking content from JSON and use jquery to open and close other content from JSON.
I really don't know how to connect jquery to navigation bar which is taking information from JSON.

I have tried to google the problem but haven't find a solution to this anywhere.

Script

```
  <script>
        $.getJSON('events.json', function (data) {
            var $menu = $('#navbarNav ul.navbar-nav');
            $.each(data, function () {
                var url = this.url || '#';
                $menu.append(
                    '<li class="nav-item">' +
                    '<a class="nav-link" href="' + url + '">' + (this.name || this.id) + '</a>' +
                    '</li>'
                );
            });
        });
    </script>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#show').click(function () {
                $('.menu').toggle("slow");
            });
        });
    </script>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $.getJSON('results.json', function (data) {
                var results_table = '';
                $.each(data, function (key, value) {
                    results_table += '<tr>';
                    results_table += '<td>' + value.Rank + '</td>';
                    results_table += '<td>' + value.Country + '</td>';
                    results_table += '<td>' + value.Athlete + '</td>';
                    results_table += '<td>' + value.Time + '</td>';
                    results_table += '<td>' + value.Points + '</td>';
                    results_table += '</tr>';
                });
                $('#results_table').append(results_table);
            });
        });
    </script>
```

HTML

```
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Events</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav"
            aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
            <ul class="navbar-nav">
        </div>
    </nav>

    <div id="show">test</div>
    <div class="container">
        <table class="table table-borderless menu" id="results_table" style="display: none;">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="col">Rank</th>
                    <th scope="col">Country</th>
                    <th scope="col">Athlete</th>
                    <th scope="col">Time</th>
                    <th scope="col">Points</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
        </table>
    </div>
```

JSON

```
[
        {
            "id" : "1", 
            "name" : "100m"
        },

        {
            "id" : "2", 
            "name" : "Long Jump"
        },

        {
            "id" : "3", 
            "name" : "Shot Put"
        },

        {
            "id" : "4", 
            "name" : "High Jump"
        }
]
```

JSON_2

```
[
    {
        "Rank": "1",
        "Country": "JPN",
        "Athlete": "Akihiko Nakamura",
        "Time": "4:18.370",
        "Points": "823"
    },
    {
        "Rank": "2",
        "Country": "AUS",
        "Athlete": "Cedric Dubler",
        "Time": "4:32.120",
        "Points": "731"
    },
    {
        "Rank": "3",
        "Country": "AUT",
        "Athlete": "Dominik Distelberger",
        "Time": "4:33.470",
        "Points": "722"
    },
    {
        "Rank": "4",
        "Country": "EST",
        "Athlete": "Karl Robert Saluri",
        "Time": "4:39.400",
        "Points": "684"
    },
    {
        "Rank": "5",
        "Country": "POL",
        "Athlete": "Pawel Wiesiolek",
        "Time": "4:42.270",
        "Points": "666"
    },
    {
        "Rank": "DNF",
        "Country": "CZE",
        "Athlete": "Jiri Sykora",
        "Time": "Did not finish",
        "Points": "0"
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So if I understand correctly, you're trying to load different JSON with results dynamically, when someone clicks on the navbar links that you've created using the data from the events.json file.

Currently, you have the AJAX call that loads the results happening on document.ready, so it's only ever going to load that results.json once.

To make this work dynamically when you click on one of the links in the navbar, you need to first move your AJAX call that loads results into a function, and then you need to let that function take a parameter that tells it which results to load.  You could do that in several ways.  If you have static JSON files for each event, you can just name them appropriately, and load them by name (i.e. 100m.json, Long_Jump.json, etc).  And then you could have the function that loads the JSON use the passed parameter.   (If you had a server side script that was dynamically creating JSON results, you could just pass the event type as a parameter to the load URL as well).

In this example, I will assume that you have statically named JSON files.

Then you need to make the links trigger that loadResults function using javascript.   In this case, I added an onClick attribute to call the function when the link is clicked on.

In the following code, I am loading the JSON files from a public Dropbox folder, but the way it loads, it will load the same JSON data for each of the different sporting events.  But it allows you to see it in action.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.getJSON('https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/wu2tc52r243vd4e/events.json', function (data) {
    var $menu = $('#navbarNav ul.navbar-nav');
    $.each(data, function () {
      var url = this.url || '#';
      $menu.append(
        '<li class="nav-item">' +
        '<a class="nav-link" href="#" onClick="loadResults(\'' + this.name + '\')">' + (this.name || this.id) + '</a>' +
        '</li>'
      );
    });
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Events</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav"
        aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
      <ul class="navbar-nav"></ul>
    </div>
</nav>

<div class="container">
    <table class="table table-borderless menu" id="results_table" style="display: none;">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th scope="col">Rank</th>
                <th scope="col">Country</th>
                <th scope="col">Athlete</th>
                <th scope="col">Time</th>
                <th scope="col">Points</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
    </table>
</div>

<script>
  var resultsLoading = false;
  function loadResults(eventType) {
    console.log("loadResults " + eventType);
    // close the menu if it was open
    $('.menu').slideUp("slow")

    // clear out the old menu
    $('#results_table tbody').empty();

    // build the JSON file name and replace spaces with underscores
    var jsonFile = eventType.split(" ").join("_") + ".json";
    
    if (!resultsLoading) {
      resultsLoading = true
      $.getJSON("https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/jqodu1jopchc93y/"+jsonFile, function (data) {
        var results_table = '';
        $.each(data, function (key, value) {
          results_table += '<tr>';
          results_table += '<td>' + value.Rank + '</td>';
          results_table += '<td>' + value.Country + '</td>';
          results_table += '<td>' + value.Athlete + '</td>';
          results_table += '<td>' + value.Time + '</td>';
          results_table += '<td>' + value.Points + '</td>';
          results_table += '</tr>';
        });
        $('#results_table').append(results_table);
        // show the menu again
        $('.menu').slideDown("slow");
        resultsLoading = false;
      });
    } else {
      console.log('results are being loaded, please wait');
    }
  }

</script>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, i used the code but ran into another problem, here's the link to the site http://digiveeb.eu/proovitoo/proovit%C3%B6%C3%B6.html

Comment: There are a couple of things happening there, which your developer tools and console can help you diagnose.  First off, with the link you provided, you're loading the page using http, but the AJAX calls are trying to load https, which causes a CORS error and won't let the AJAX load.  If you load your URL with https (https://digiveeb.eu/proovitoo/proovit%C3%B6%C3%B6.html), then it will properly load the events.json.

Comment: Secondly, you're trying to load the results with `$.getJSON("results.json"+jsonFile,...` but the jsonFile variable will be something like `100m.json` or `Long_Jump.json`, so you're trying to load a file called `results.json100m.json`.   So if you name your results files accordingly, and then just do `$.getJSON(jsonFile,...` it should work better.

Comment: And finally, you still have it trying to load results.json on $(document).ready()

Comment: Okai, thanks i did everything you told me to and it looks good, but now i need help removing double click stacking, when you double click on "Pole Vault" Then there will be 2 tables ontop of eachother, how to make it so it pops back in with the second click?

Comment: Great, glad it's working for you!  There are a few ways to handle the double click.  One way is to not allow more AJAX requests to happen until the last one has finished.  (With this one, you might want make sure you handle any errors properly if it fails to load the JSON, otherwise you might get yourself stuck being unable to load more results because it is still waiting for a failed AJAX call to finish).  Another option would be to abort the current AJAX call when a new one comes in, which would require setting an xhr variable to your `$.getJSON` so that you can abort it...

Comment: I went ahead and edited my running example above and added a `resultsLoading` boolean variable, which is originally set to false.  Then when it's about to do an AJAX call, it checks to make sure it is false, then it sets it to true and does the AJAX.  Finally, it sets it back to false when it's done processing the AJAX call.   You can see the console messages when you run my example code snippet.  And if you double click, you can see it log that it was still running the last one.

Comment: Once you get yours working the way you like, you can go ahead and mark this as an accepted answer...